# Pitfall in Swift Type Casting

Tags: swift

I am not totally sure if this the right place to post this, as it is more a pitfall I have found than a question I would ask. (Although I would be very interested if someone could explain the reason why this happens.)

So in my Swift iOS-app I had to use Objective-C Arrays for sorting. I knew for a fact that the `NSMutableArray` called `results` would contain only `MyObject`s. Thus, after sorting I cast it to `[MyObject]` like this to save it in the variable `myArrayVar : [MyObject]`.

```
myArrayVar = (results as NSArray) as [MyObject]
```

This worked fine *until I tested it on a release build*. There it crashed. What I had to do to fix the crash was this:

```
if let results = results as Any as? NSArray {
    if let results = results as? [MyObject] {
        myArrayVar = results
    } else { NSLog("the impossible happened.") }
} else { NSLog("the impossible happened.") }
```

Now we can see that this version cannot crash when the casting goes wrong whereas the first version would. However, the cast *does not go wrong* as I could verify by never seeing the log message.
So what might be the difference at runtime between these two versions of type casting? Whatever it is I have the feeling it might be a pitfall for others as well.